# How do I add Multiple Objects of a similar type to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have seen several solutions to adding objects to local storage on here and some other sites but my problem is slightly different. I want to save several related items to local storage.
Something like this

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type='text' id='firstname' placeholder="first name"><br>
<input type='text' id='surname' placeholder="surname"><br>
<button id='submit'>Add</button>

<div id='displaynames'>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){

        firstname = $('#firstname').val();
        surname = $('#surname').val();
        $('#displaynames').append("<p>"+firstname+" "+surname+"</p>");

        var names = {
            id: //what goes here?,
            name: firstname,
            lastname: surname
        };

        localStorage.setItem('names:'+counter, JSON.stringify(names));
        counter++;
        $('#displaynames').html(localStorage.getItem('names'));

    });
})   
</script>
</body>
```

all properties of this object will be supplied by the user but no two objects will have the same id to distinguish them and more importantly, no two object can have the same key name, how could this be implemented? some  kind of loop somewhere in my code?

I will like the key to increment like names:1, names:2, names:3 etc

Comment: What do you need the `id` for? Why not just use `counter` for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can also store the `counter` itself in the localStorage so each time you need to add a new item, you make sure to increment the counter.

```
// Get current counter from LS and increment it
var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
counter++;

// Put names in LS with a new counter id
localStorage.setItem('names:'+counter, JSON.stringify(names));

// Put back the incremented counter into LS
localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
```

But as suggested in a comment it would be wiser to use an array on which you put all your `names`. When adding a new name, its `id` could simply be `"names:" + namesArray.length`

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array, you can store objects in an array, my example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allNames = [];
  $('button').click(function() {
    firstname = $('#firstname').val();
    surname = $('#surname').val();
    $('#displaynames').append("<p>" + firstname + " " + surname + "</p>");

    var names = {
      id: allNames.length,
      name: firstname,
      lastname: surname
    };

    allNames.push(names);

    localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(allNames));
    $('#displaynames').html(localStorage.getItem('names'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='firstname' placeholder="first name">
<br>
<input type='text' id='surname' placeholder="surname">
<br>
<button id='submit'>Add</button>

<div id='displaynames'></div>
```

I hope the snippet works. If it doesn't, what I'm trying to do is create an array with the object to store:

```
[
    {
       id: 0,
       name: "Foo",
       lastname: "Bar"
    },
{
       id: 1,
       name: "Bar",
       lastname: "Foo"
    },
{
       id: 2,
       name: "Bob",
       lastname: "Joe"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to store similar type objects via concatenated reference to their IDs:

```
    let productBag = window.localStorage.getItem("product_id");

    console.log(productBag);

    if (productBag != undefined) {

      let tempData = productBag + "," + product['_id'];
      window.localStorage.setItem("product_id", tempData);

    } else {

      window.localStorage.setItem("product_id", product['_id']);

    }
```

Code to display an item by its ID:

```
 var test =  window.localStorage.getItem("product_id")

 console.log(test.split(","));
```