# how to push multiple json object in localstorage

Tags: jquery

I want to add multiple JSON objects in localStorage, Now I can add a single JSON object only and also attached my code. I refer this link but can not solve [Push JSON Objects to array in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083919/push-json-objects-to-array-in-localstorage) please resolve this issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>


 <div class="container">
     <div id="gvalue"></div>
  <form >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $('document').ready(function(){
        $('.btn').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();

          var name=$("#email").val();
          var pwd=$("#pwd").val();

      // window.localStorage.setItem("name","siva");
      var testLocal={

        name:name,
        pwd:pwd,
      };

      window.localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(testLocal));




 });
         var getItm=window.localStorage.getItem('user');

      console.log(getItm);

      // document.getElementById('gvalue').innerHTML=getItm;
      $("#gvalue").append(getItm);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an array?

Comment: please use JSON array and resolve this issue

Comment: I found the solution link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133664/how-do-i-add-multiple-objects-of-a-similar-type-to-local-storage thanks for your support